Ошибка SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
Почему сервер не получает данные корректно из БД и выскакивает ошибка в консоли?
`
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import axios from 'axios';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:5173'}));

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/impetus_project')
  .then((res) => console.log('Conected to MongoDB'))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));

let cardFestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: Number,
  title: String,
  img: String,
})
let cardFest = mongoose.model('cardFest', cardFestSchema)

app.listen(port, () =>{
  console.log(`localhost:${port}`);
})

app.get('/main', async (req, res) => {
  let card = await cardFest.find();
  res.send(card);
})



Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

res.json(card);
